# Class Design with RestKit + CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit

I have a fairly basic question and I am sure I am missing something basic but this is my first time using RK + CD so any help is appreciated.

I have a data set:

```
@interface A :NSManagedObject{
NSString *content;
NSString *userId;
}
```

I POST this to the server from one view.

In another view I GET a list of these data sets back. So I get an array of the following items from the server.

Ideally I should be able to create a base class A which I can use for both POST and GET.
But since I am storing the GET response in CoreData, A is a NSManagedObject. GET works great and I can display all the entries I get from the server but here is the POST code.

For POST, my requestDescriptor looks like this:

```
RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping objectClass:[A class] rootKeyPath:nil method:RKRequestMethodAny];
```

I would like to do the following when posting the entry because this entry is not in my Core data and user just entered it in my UI and I want to update it on my server rather than saving it in CD.

```
A *aObject = [[A new]init];
aObject.content = @"bla bla";
aObject.userId = "me";

    [[sharedObjectManager HTTPClient] setDefaultHeader:@"content-type" value:RKMIMETypeJSON];
[sharedObjectManager setRequestSerializationMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];

// POST to create
[sharedObjectManager postObject:aObject path:POST parameters:nil success:nil failure:nil];
```

But I cant do this since "A" is managed object and I get this error 
2014-03-11 13:55:22.511[39817:70b] CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'A' 
2014-03-11 13:55:22.511 [39817:70b] -[A setContent:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d41360

Do I have to create 2 copies of the Class A -  one for POST (Managed) and one for GET (unmanaged) - seems like an awful waste especially if there are quite a few POST and GET apis?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You don't need to do:

```
A *aObject = [[A new]init];
```

you should be creating (inserting) the new instance into the MOC. Usually when you do this the item is a stub object (partially populated with data) and will be filled in from the response that you receive from the server.

You don't need to do that. If you don't want stub objects then you can use another class (custom, or a dictionary depending on how many things you POST).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response - I was just editing my question to be more understandable :)  How can i post with a dictionary? Will postObject function take a dictionary of key value pairs? and if yes how will my requestDescriptor look?

Comment: Descriptor is the same except for `[NSDictionary class]`. This approach only really works if you only post 1 thing (because you have 1 mapping linked to the dictionary class...)

Comment: you mean if i have only one POST api?

Comment: basically yes. You can cheat and create one uber-mapping that covers all dictionaries, but it isn't nice. Custom subclasses of `NSObject` is better...

Comment: I got it! so if i create an object in the MOC, i need to reconcile it with the response I get from the server.. Basically when the client POSTs, server creates a new ID for this post ,adds it to its db, and sends it out to everyone. Now when I get this back in my GET response, whats the best way to reconcile the 2? Should i track the ID reserve returns in the POST response?

Comment: Yes, you should have a response descriptor for the posted object which updates it with the id. `postObject:...` always applies the response data to the source `object`

Comment: It all works now - Thank you so much :) It doesnt let me accept this as answer because i dont have enough reputation.. but this is the right answer. thanks again!

Comment: Good stuff. I think you can always tick an answer to your question, just not up vote...